# Python + Selenium. CSS Selector or Xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

How to find CSS selector in the hint table on https://yandex.ru/?

Search for underlined CSS doesn't work (`.mini-suggest__popup.mini-suggest__popup_svg_yes.mini-suggest__popup_theme_flat.mini-suggest__popup_visible`)

```
    browser.implicitly_wait(5)
try:
    suggest = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.mini-suggest__popup.mini-suggest__popup_svg_yes.mini-suggest__popup_theme_flat.mini-suggest__popup_visible`')
except NoSuchElementException: 
print('no table with hints')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use CSS selector `div.mini-suggest__popup`. Here is complete example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

wd = webdriver.Chrome('<<PATH_TO_CHROMEDRIVER>>', options=chrome_options)

url = 'https://yandex.ru'

# load page via selenium
wd.get(url)

# wait 5 seconds until page will be loaded
text_input = WebDriverWait(wd, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'text')))
text_input.send_keys('Hello world')

# wait for popup to appear
popup = WebDriverWait(wd, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.mini-suggest__popup')))

# wait for popup third child and click it
WebDriverWait(popup, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li:nth-child(3)'))).click();
```

Comment: Can I check without clicking on popup third child? Because after that I have to press ENTER and continue testing

Comment: Sure. In that case you provide selector / xpath for the last `WebDriverWait` instance, check its text without clicking it and continue with further actions.

Comment: But how do I know what text will be in the last copy. so I need to check the text before the test starts?

Comment: That depends on the purpose of your test. If it's needed to check that the suggestions popup is shown, than you can just get li elements. If it's needed to check, how many of them are shown, you can check length of the returned list. If it's needed to check that some particular suggestion is shown, you can check for presence of particular text.

Comment: I was hoping that there is some element that will tell me that the popup is visible to the user and thought that it is mini-suggest__popup_visible(it is last class in my CSS_selector) , it only appears when the popup is open
P.S. or is it unreal>? :D

Comment: For that purpose you could use `EC.visibility_of_element_located`.

Comment: popup = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.mini-suggest__popup.mini-suggest__popup_theme_flat.mini-suggest__popup_visible')))
except TimeoutException:
print('No popup')
Thank you very mach!

Comment: Sorry, i mistake popup = WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((.......